# Julia 'glob' for file paths starting with forward slash

Tags: julia

How can I use Julia's glob to extract file names of a given format, if the file paths start with forward slash, as is the case on the linux-based computing cluster I use.

For example:

```
using Glob
file_paths  =  glob("/global/cdirs/stuff/*_*_*.csv")
```

fails with

```
Glob pattern cannot be empty or start with a / character
```

Answer (score 2):

`glob` does not accept absolute paths as its first argument (there's [an issue](https://github.com/vtjnash/Glob.jl/issues/2) about adding it). Instead, you can use the two-argument form of `glob`, where the second argument is the directory under which the glob should be matched. So, in this case, you can do:

```
using Glob
file_paths  =  glob("*_*_*.csv", "/global/cdirs/stuff/")
```

One base Julia way to get the same result would be

```
dir = "/global/cdirs/stuff"
filter(readdir(dir, join = true)) do f
  contains(f, Regex("^$dir/.*_.*_.*\\.csv\$"))
end
```

but the glob way may be easier to maintain in the long run since more people are comfortable with globs than regexes.